# What's the difference beetwen EntityManager and DAO?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dao, entitymanager

What's the difference beetwen EntityManager and DAO? Is it same thing?

Comment: Context, please? Do you mean in Java? In COBOL?

Comment: I'm working in JAVA EE platform. OOP patterns are different for different programming languages?

Comment: The concept `EntityManager` refers to a specific thing in J2EE, most likely. It may or may not exist in .NET, and if it does, may be called something different. It is not an "OOP Pattern" as far as I know.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Comment: I saw the implementation of the EM in one project. It was used as DAO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EntityManager is an interface provided by JPA, which provides generic methods used to persist, merge, find and create queries for entities.

DAO is a pattern used to isolate database-access code in a separate component (the DAO) so that services concentrate on the business logic rather than low-level database stuff. It helps in unit-testing the service, and in separating responsibilities.

When using JPA, you typically write one DAO per entity, that will contain all the JPA code (queries, mostly) related to that entity. And this DAO uses the EntityManager.